# How to check if the element changes its class with Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a website with the following HTML. First, the element would be:

```
<div class="hidden sc-cHGsZl ghXVcK" role="alert" id="login-error"></div>
```

Then after you unsuccessfully login, it will change to:

```
<div class="sc-cHGsZl ghXVcK" role="alert" id="login-error">
    <span>Incorrect email address and / or password.<br>
     Do you need help <a href="/login/resetpassword?email=xxxxx">logging in</a>?
    </span>
</div>
```

What I currently do:

```
errors = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//div[@id='login-error']//span[contains(., 'Incorrect email address and / or password.')]")
```

I have a few questions as follow:

1. How should I check for the unsuccessfully login?
2. I couldn't output the content of this `errors`; how should I do it?
   Thank you guys! Have a nice day!

Comment: "How should I check for the unsuccessfully login" - this depends on goals of your test. There might be several assertions you need to do. You can check **visibility** of `driver.find_element_by_id("login-error")`. Then check whether text of Error message is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1. How should I check for the unsuccessfully login?

Basically you can wrap your login code inside a **try-except :**

**Code :**

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("user name xpath").send_keys('username')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("password xpath").send_keys('password')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('login button xpath').click()
    if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Incorrect email address')]")) > 0:
        print("if code has reached here that means login was not successful")
        # assert login failure here if you want
    else:
        print("login must have been successful since Incorrect email address web element was not found")
except:
    print("something went wrong")
    pass
```

for second question, you can have this line

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Incorrect email address')]").text)
```

in if block after this line `print("if code has reached here that means login was not successful")`

Comment: It didn't work sadly; it only output empty lines. :(( Update: it works now so sorry. I have one following up question. It seems that if I add the driver.close() after the print command, it will not print out anything. What would be a reason for it?

Comment: Did you make use of asserts ? also where have you put `driver.close` ? remember to place it when you want to terminate your code execution.

Comment: I realized it was because of the latency. Thank you so much!